# SVG() y coordinate not matching height

Tags: svg.js

when I set `viewbox(0,0,100,100)` and I then set some text `draw.text('Hello Word').y(100)` when I console log `y` its `115.3996229171753` i was expecting 100?
Thanks in advance.

```
const svg = SVG().addTo(".wrapper");
svg.viewbox(0, 0, 100, 100);
const { width, height } = svg.viewbox();
svg.rect(100, 100).fill("tomato");
svg.plain("Hello Javascript").fill("blue").y(height);
```

Comment: I'm presuming svg.js calculates the height of the text?

Comment: But i would like the baseline of the text to sit at the bottom of the svg

Comment: svg.js positions bei top left edge but text is positioned by baseline. thats why its different. use "amove() / ay() / ax()" to move by the text-anchor (=baseline)

Comment: Thank you,  as always very great full for your responses. What’s the best way of finding this information?

Comment: Thank you,  as always very grateful for your answers. I looked up the docs and found the amove description. I must have missed it presuming it was another move () description